# How to generate numbers which is containing only 0's and 9's

Tags: c++, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, generator

Hi I want to generate numbers which is contain only 0's and 9's in python or c++ doesn't matter
I write it like:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    random_number = 9 * 10**i
    for j in range(0,i):
        second_sum = 9 *10 ** j
        random_number += second_sum
    print(random_number)
```

but output like this

```
9
99
999
9999
99999
999999
9999999
99999999
999999999
9999999999
............
..............
```

But expected output is

```
9
90
99
900
909
990
999
9000
9009
9090
9099
9900
9990
9999
--snip--
```

Anyone help me please :)

Comment: "in python or c++" then why tag C and not C++?  Tags adjusted.

Comment: you could count in binary and replace the ones...

Comment: You have the alphabet of two chars '0' and '9', it's just a binary alphabet of '0' and '1', but '1' is replaced with '9', that absolutely does not have a matter. Just start with int number 1, convert it to a string of binary chars, replace '1' with '9', increase the number. Repeat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on @B.Go's comment, here's solution with replacing the ones:

```
def generate(n=5):
    for i in range(1, 2**n):
        yield int('{:b}'.format(i).replace('1', '9'))

print([*generate(5)])
```

Prints:

```
[9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999, 90000, 90009, 90090, 90099, 90900, 90909, 90990, 90999, 99000, 99009, 99090, 99099, 99900, 99909, 99990, 99999]
```

Comment: Just multiply by 9.

Answer (score 5):

(**EDITED**)

Your approach would not work because:

- you are not printing `random_number` just often enough.
- even if you were, you are not producing all the possible permutations with repetitions.

```
for i in range(0, 3):
    random_number = 9 * 10 ** i
    print(random_number)  # <--- HERE
    for j in range(0, i):
        second_sum = 9 * 10 ** j
        random_number += second_sum
        print(random_number)  # <--- HERE

# 9
# 90
# 99
# 900
# 909
# 999
```

`990` is missing and this approach is not easy to generalize, as it would need an arbitrary number of nested loops.

---

There are several other possible approaches, either based on [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) (which is more general and simpler to extend as an infinite generator) or on the observation that a binary representation of the natural numbers is very close to your target output:

```
import itertools


def my_gen_itertools(max_len=0, items='09'):
    length = 1
    while max_len and length <= max_len:
        for x in itertools.product(items, repeat=length):
            if x[0] != items[0]:
                yield int(''.join(x))
        length += 1


def my_gen_bin_mult(n, factor=9):
    for i in range(1, 2 ** n):
        yield int(bin(i)[2:]) * factor


def my_gen_bin_replace(n, subst='9'):
    for i in range(1, 2 ** n):
        yield int('{:b}'.format(i).replace('1', subst))


def my_gen_bit_mult(n, factor=9):
    k = [10 ** i for i in range(n)]
    for value in range(1, 2 ** n):
        result = 0
        j = 0
        while value:
            result += (value & 1) * k[j]
            value >>= 1
            j += 1
        yield result * factor
```

Note that `my_gen_bin_replace()` is essentially the solution proposed in [@AndrejKesely's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230117/5218354) except that is uses the more efficient `bin()` call for obtaining the binary representation, and both `my_gen_bin_replace()` and `my_gen_bin_mult()` are implement the approach proposed in [@Orace's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230078/5218354).

`my_gen_bit_mult()` is similar to `my_gen_bin_mult()` except that this is handled without the intermediate string representation, but uses the rather expensive power computation and Python direct loopings, **but it would be the easiest to convert to C++ (where direct looping would not be that slow).**

---

Speed-wise, multiplying the binary representation seems to be the fastest:

```
funcs = my_gen_itertools, my_gen_bin_mult, my_gen_bin_replace, my_gen_bit_mult
for func in funcs:
    print()
    print(func.__name__)
    print(list(func(4)))
    %timeit list(func(20))

# my_gen_itertools
# [9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 839 ms per loop

# my_gen_bin_mult
# [9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 572 ms per loop

# my_gen_bin_replace
# [9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 739 ms per loop

# my_gen_bit_mult
# [9, 90, 99, 900, 909, 990, 999, 9000, 9009, 9090, 9099, 9900, 9909, 9990, 9999]
# 1 loop, best of 3: 3.97 s per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for doing the benchmark, the `my_gen_bin_mult()` seems to work best...

Answer (score 3):

You just need one loop, say `i` in `[0..100]`, convert `i` to it's binary representation (only 0 and 1), and replace the 1 by 9 (if you have an integer at this point, you can multiply by 9).

Here a method that convert any integer to a string of it's binary representation but with 0&9 instead of 0&1.

```
n=int(input('please enter the no. in decimal format: '))
x=n
k=[]
while (n>0):
    a=int(float(n%2))
    k.append(a)
    n=(n-a)/2
k.append(0)
string=""
for j in k[::-1]:
    string=string+str(j*9)
print('The binary no. for %d is %s'%(x, string))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not the best performing version, and it may be refined for your needs, but it can be an idea for a solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def with_digits(n):
    assert(n > 0)
    if n == 1:
        return [0, 9]

    prevs = with_digits(n-1)
    values = [] + prevs
    for prev in prevs:
        values.append(9 * 10 ** (n-1) + prev)
    return values

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(with_digits(5))
```